# Unreadable text on some menus

Tags: menu

Been using Ubuntu for a while first time asking a question, and excuse me as I am not very technical.
I am getting some unusual scrambling of fonts in menu's on most applications making them impossible to read but am unsure how to fix it.

**Edit**:
 First time. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 10 yearold iMac whose OS was about to go out of support with no more upgrade path from Apple, it was to highly specked to ditch though as it is an I7 with 32GB mem. I checked the graphics card and got the following: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M]

**Edit**:
I installed from a bootable USB drive and I accepted all the defaults did not see anything about HWE.
I ran the commands but there was only a couple of nautilus packages.
I checked the status of hwe and received this response:
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.
Hope that helps

[image: Chrome Menu]
[image: Notepad Menu]

Comment: I don't know your hardware, nor did you give your release details, but my guess is you're using a `radeon` driver and possibly your issue relates to https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1841718   Providing full release details, even kernel (ie. if using 18.04 or a LTS release, do you have HWE enabled) allows us to provide more - ie. I'm just guessing given the little you provided..  Is your system fully-updated?  Are you using an up-to-date mirror, though release & kernel details may make these questions mute..

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question (you can edit your own question, and many of us can edit to help correct any formatting issues there; comments can only be deleted), don't reply in comments.  Is your Ubuntu 18.04 installed, if so what media was used to install it (i'm trying to determine if HWE is enabled assuming you didn't enable/disable it intentionally; HWE is the hardware enablement stack allowing an LTS release; 18.04 from 2018-April, to use 18.10's kernel/stack, 19.04's, or later stacks). If installed are you fully upgraded? (`sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`)